# Android: Call ViewModel function with Data Binding

Tags: android, binding, android-jetpack

I'm trying to use Data Binding for setting onClick listeners for buttons in my fragment.

The function that I need to be called every time "next" button is pressed is in a View Model.

I managed to bind data from View Model to my layout XML but I am still unable to call functions from a view model :/

I'm getting this error when trying to call ViewModel functions:

```
C:\Users\Michal\git\fitness-fatality\app\build\generated\source\kapt\debug\com\example\fitnessfatality\DataBinderMapperImpl.java:10: error: cannot find symbol
import com.example.fitnessfatality.databinding.FragmentWorkoutLoggingBindingImpl;
                                              ^
  symbol:   class FragmentWorkoutLoggingBindingImpl
  location: package com.example.fitnessfatality.databinding
```

I've also tried calling view model functions like this:

```
android:onClick="@{viewModel.incrementIndex()}"
```

However, if I bind the entire fragment, I am able to call its functions.

This is how I've tried implementing on click binding with view model:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout
        android:id="@+id/main_linear_container"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data>
        <import type="com.example.fitnessfatality.ui.workoutTracking.viewModels.TrackingViewModel"/>
        <import type="java.util.List"/>
        <import type="com.example.fitnessfatality.ui.workoutTracking.TrackingFragment" />
        <variable name="viewModel" type="TrackingViewModel" />
        <variable name="fragment" type="TrackingFragment" />
    </data>

    <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_width="match_parent">

//More layouts


                <Button
                        android:text="Next"
                        android:onClick="@{viewModel.incrementIndex}"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/btn_next" android:layout_weight="1"/>
        </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

And in my fragment I have

```
 private lateinit var trackingViewModel: TrackingViewModel

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        trackingViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(TrackingViewModel::class.java)
    }

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val binding =
            DataBindingUtil.inflate<FragmentWorkoutLoggingBinding>(
                inflater,
                R.layout.fragment_workout_logging,
                container,
                false
            )

        binding.lifecycleOwner = this
        binding.viewModel = trackingViewModel
        binding.fragment = this

        return binding.root
    }
```

And my ViewModel:

```
class TrackingViewModel(application: Application): BaseViewModel(application) {
    val workoutExercises: LiveData<List<WorkoutExercisePojo>>
    private val workoutExerciseRepository: WorkoutExerciseRepository

    val currentIndex: MutableLiveData<Int> = MutableLiveData()

    val index: LiveData<Int> = currentIndex

    init {
        val db = AppDatabase.getDatabase(application, scope)
        workoutExerciseRepository = WorkoutExerciseRepository(db.workoutExerciseDao())
        workoutExercises = workoutExerciseRepository.allWorkoutExercises
        currentIndex.value = 0
    }

    fun incrementIndex() {
        currentIndex.value = currentIndex.value!!.plus(1)
    }
}
```

Comment: "I am still unable to call functions from a view model" -- what does this mean? What are your symptoms? I would expect a binding expression of `@{viewModel.incrementIndex()}` to work.

Comment: I'm getting an error in the generated files when I try `@{viewModel.incrementIndex()}`. I've updated my description with the error message

Comment: "I'm getting this error when trying to call ViewModel functions" -- if you look in the build output, you should be getting other error messages related to the data binding layout resources.

Comment: I'm not, I'm only getting the error I added to the description in the build console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the custom BindingAdapter:

```
@BindingAdapter("onClick")
fun onClick(view: View, onClick: () -> Unit) {
    view.setOnClickListener {
        onClick()
    }
}
```

You should be able to directly bind a viewmodel function like

```
app:onClick="@{viewModel::forgotPasswordClicked}"
```

in your XML. This would then lead to a viewmodel function like:

```
fun forgotPasswordClicked() {
    TODO("ForgotPasswordClicked")
}
```

This way, you also don't have to import unnecessary Android-Dependencies into your viewmodel.

Comment: its better to use `android:onClick-"@{()->vm.yourFun()}"` works without importing android  classes and no need to create binding adapter

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solved. The problem was that `incremenetIndex` function in ViewModel did not accept View as a parameter.

So now, the function in ViewModel looks like this:

```
fun incrementIndex(view: View) {
    currentIndex.value = currentIndex.value!!.plus(1)
}
```

Comment: How did you pass `view` argument when calling this function from XML?

Comment: I don't remember exactly how I did this back then but you can pass view from your fragment when calling the function or from XML layout if you're using data binding. You might also want to consider having an interface that provides any UI interactions.